# Smooth maps to singular sets

Tags: real-analysis, singularity-theory

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be an affine variety
(that is, a set given by polynomial equations).
One may suppose $X$ singular
(the case of non-singular $X$ is obvious).

Is it true that
any continuous map $[0,1]^m\to X$ can be $C^0$-approximated by a smooth one?

A map $[0,1]^m\to X$ is called smooth if
its composition with the inclusion
$$
[0,1]^m\to X\to\mathbb R^n
$$
is smooth (that is, $C^\infty$).